# ScrollViewer ignores ContentTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, scrollviewer

I've faced with issue, using `ScrollViewer`.
Here's sample view models:

```
public class A
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

...and `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
public class ViewModelTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ATemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate BTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is A)
            return ATemplate;

        if (item is B)
            return BTemplate;

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ViewModelTemplateSelector x:Key="ViewModelTemplateSelectorKey">
            <local:ViewModelTemplateSelector.ATemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:ViewModelTemplateSelector.ATemplate>
            <local:ViewModelTemplateSelector.BTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:ViewModelTemplateSelector.BTemplate>
        </local:ViewModelTemplateSelector>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    <ScrollViewer   Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListBox}"  
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ViewModelTemplateSelectorKey}"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListBox}"                       
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ViewModelTemplateSelectorKey}"/>
</Grid>
```

This is what is going on, when any item is selected in `ListBox`:

[image]

As you can see, `ScrollViewer` ignores `ContentTemplateSelector`, while `ContentControl` does not. `ScrollViewer` is inherited from `ContentControl`, and at first look, there's no reason for such behavior.

I know, that if I'll declare implicit data templates for `A` and `B`, `ScrollViewer` will handle them correctly, but this is not an option for my real application.

Is this known bug? Or am I missing something?

**UPD**.

I've submitted an [issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1064425/wpf-scrollviewer-ignores-datatemplateselector) on MS Connect.

Comment: Do you ever reach SelectTemplate method ?

Comment: @eranotzap: no, it is never fired for `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: ScrollViewer usese a ScrollContentPresenter to render it's content i'm guessing it does not apply the given ContentTemplate like it does when rendered directly under a ContentControl.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test the syntax.  If it is wrong just let me know and I will delete
This is what I would try

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListBox}"                       
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ViewModelTemplateSelectorKey}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not interesting about workaround. The question was exactly about `ScrollViewer`'s behavior: may be there are some features or bugs, which I'm not familiar with. Since I'm using the same workaround, that you've posted, I'll up-vote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListBox}"  ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ViewModelTemplateSelectorKey}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: (plus one)  , I like this answer , i need to check this assumption , but i bellive ScrollViewer will know to ignore it's own ContentPresenter ( i.e. the ScrollContentPresenter )
And use the one you gave it declaratively  like you did.